# Text data stored differently

Tags: python, pandas, tableau-api

My problem is I have 2 values which should be the same, however they have this strange difference I don't know where its coming from.

The context is I have imported 3 files using pd.read_csv. I grouped the values using groupby, using some date field, and aggregated the offending variable using nunique, just to keep record of the count.

Then, using Tableau it actually counted different number unique records. I found a pair of records pandas says are different, while Tableau sees as equals.

Take a look:

```
df
      A
0     100000306
1     100000306

x1 = df.iloc[0,0]
str(x1.values)
"['100000306']"

x2 = df.iloc[1,0]
str(x2.values)
'[100000306]'
```

Why is this happening and what can I do so pandas knows they are the same value?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

I'm not sure what other processing steps you have done with your data but it seems the value stored in [0,0] is a string `'100000306'` as opposed to an integer `100000306`. What you could do is to use [pandas.to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) in order to convert values in your column to float values where possible

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different type in one columns

```
df.applymap(type)
               A
0  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'int'>
```

Notice when you print df.A it will show object

```
df.A
0    100000306
1    100000306
Name: A, dtype: object
```